# How to hide connectionStrings on Github for both Entity Framework and Membership, that will be used on AppHarbor later on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, github, asp.net-membership, appharbor

I know the title looks somewhat confusing so let me explain. :)

I have a MVC 3.0 Project for which I maintain a public repository @ github, and said Project utilizes the Entity Framework and the Membership Provider (so that's two separate connectionStrings) .

The issue I am having is that the "Alias" attribute of Sequilizer for the MS SQL database, let's me specify only one connectionString value to be replaced at build time. Because I can not modify web.config programmatically (and web.config transformations are not applicable because it will leave my sensitive data open to the World on the public github repo), I am left to choose which I want to use more -> Entity or Membership (the other solution would be leaving one of my connectionStrings vulnerable) .

Due to the need of MembershipProvider to know the connectionStringName at build time (everything is specified in web.config), I am kinda at a loss of how to go about all this.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: If you want source control but are worried about having it open to the public on github, why not use bitbucket which is private (and free!) so only people you invite can access your repository..

Comment: Maybe you should consider not using the Membership stuff since it tends to produce problems like the one you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys, I think I set up everything finally.

What I did is, I used the Alias only for my normal connection string which will provide Membership stuff - while I overrode the ObjectContext default constructor (in "MyProjectEntities.Designer.cs") to use Configuration Variable (named "EntityFramework") that I set up on AppHarbor which holds the Entity Framework connectionString like so:

```
public MyProjectEntities() : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntityFramework"].ToString(), "eTestHubEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

Tested and works as I wanted it to work. :)